# unable to retrive the query related procedures

Tags: oracle

please help out

I have one query, i want to know which procedure used that query.
is there any way to sort it out?

I have tried following query.
select distinct name from all_source where text like '(my query)';

but due to spaces or something else, I am not getting the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use rare-used identifier from this query or set of identifiers. Say, if query looks like

```
select field1, field2 as field3
from table1 t, table2 tt
```

try someting like

```
select 
  owner,
  name
from 
  (select owner, name from all_source where lower(text) like '%field1%') s1 natural join
  (select owner, name from all_source where lower(text) like '%field2%') s2 natural join
  (select owner, name from all_source where lower(text) like '%field3%') s3 natural join
  (select owner, name from all_source where lower(text) like '%table1%') s4 natural join
  (select owner, name from all_source where lower(text) like '%table2%') s5 natural join
  (select owner, name from all_source where lower(text) like '%tt%') s6
```

so you'll find a small number of candidates which you can check manually.